# Writing $\sigma$-algebra in terms of predictble processes?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, filtrations

If $X_t$ is a semi-martingale, $\mathfrak{F}_t$ is the $\sigma$-field generated by $X_t$ and $L^2(Pred)$ is the set of all $\mathfrak{F}_t$-predictible processes.  Then is it true that:
$$
\mathfrak{G}_t \triangleq \sigma\left(
H\cdot X_t : H \in L^2(Pred)
\right)
=
\mathfrak{F}_t?
$$

Comment: no, $X_t$ could be identically 0.

Comment: So?  This has nothing to do with $X_t$ but with Sigma fields.  The point is that are the sigma fields determined entirely by the set of processes which are predictable wrt to it.

Comment: doesn't your notation $H \cdot X_t$ mean stochastic integrals with respect to $X_t$ ?

Comment: @michael: If $X$ is identically $0$, then both $\mathfrak F_t$ and $\mathfrak G_t$ are trivial for each $t\ge 0$.

Comment: You are, in my opinion, missing a comma, i.e.  by $X_t$, and ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, at least if $X_0=0$.  The containment $\mathfrak G_t\subset\mathfrak F_t$ is clear. In the other direction, is $0<s\le t$ then $X_s=(H\cdot X)_t$, where $H_u(\omega) :=1_{]0,s]}(u)$ is (trivially) predictable. This shows that $X_s$ is $\mathfrak G_t$-mesurable for each $s\in]0,t]$.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you John, this is perfect!